# Ubuntu Software Center not opening in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, software-center

I was trying open ubuntu softwarecenter in a terminal. 
But it did not open. Please help!

Error:

```
014-09-26 04:19:02,950 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 130, in <module>
    app = SoftwareCenterAppGtk3(options, args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 357, in __init__
    Gdk.Screen.get_default())
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/utils.py", line 89, in init_sc_css_provider
    provider.load_from_path(css_path)
gi._glib.GError: softwarecenter.css:1:0Expected a valid selector
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your issue but you're not already aware you can also install apps by using

```
sudo apt-get install (application name)
```

Sorry that I can't solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

$software-center

should do it. If you want to use command line to install a package then the correct way to do it would be

$sudo apt-get install package-name

or

$sudo apt-get remove package-name

to remove it. If you want a text based package manager then you could have a look at aptitude:

Try to update

sudo aptitude